# Empty array response to Get request

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, angular-fullstack

I am following a full-stack web development guide. The git repository can be found here:
https://github.com/cliveharber/gettingMean-2/tree/chapter-06

In chapter 6, I've created an API that is supposed to display a list of locations based on the GPS coordinates. When I test the get request I get an empty array. The get request URL is:
http://localhost:3000/api/locations?lat=51.455041&lng=-0.9690884

This is the controller code for locations:
Note that I use a Mongoose aggregate called $geonear to find a list of locations close to a specified point

```js
  

const locationsListByDistance = async (req, res) => {
  const lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);
  const lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
  const near = {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [lng, lat]
  };
  const geoOptions = {
    distanceField: "distance.calculated",
    key: 'coords',
    spherical: true,
    maxDistance: 20000
  };
  if (!lng || !lat) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .json({ "message": "lng and lat query parameters are required" });
  }

  try {
    const results = await Loc.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near,
          ...geoOptions
        }
      }
    ]);
    const locations = results.map(result => {
      return {
        id: result._id,
        name: result.name,
        address: result.address,
        rating: result.rating,
        facilities: result.facilities,
        distance: `${result.distance.calculated.toFixed()}m`
      }
    });
    res
      .status(200)
      .json(locations);
  } catch (err) {
    res
      .status(404)
      .json(err);
  }
};
```

This is my location model:

```js
   

 const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      address: String,
      rating: {
        type: Number,
        'default': 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
      },
      facilities: [String],
      coords: {
        type: {type: String},
        coordinates: [Number]
      },
      openingTimes: [openingTimesSchema],
      reviews: [reviewSchema]
    });
```

I am sure I use the right GPS coordinates in the get request URL. This the document I am trying to retrieve from the database:

[image]

I am not sure why I'm getting an empty array when testing this API. Are there any issues in my code?

Comment: In the future, please post text inline rather than as a screenshot.  It is much friendlier to mobile users, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code right, the aggregation that you are sending is:

```
Loc.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          {
           type: "Point",
           coordinates: [lng, lat]
          },
          distanceField: "distance.calculated",
          key: 'coords',
          spherical: true,
          maxDistance: 20000 
        }
      }
    ]);
```

You haven't mentioned creating a 2dsphere index on the `coords` field of the collection, I'll assume you have done that.

That aggregation seems to be missing the `near` field name, like:

```
Loc.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
                 type: "Point",
                 coordinates: [lng, lat]
          },
          distanceField: "distance.calculated",
          key: 'coords',
          spherical: true,
          maxDistance: 20000 
        }
      }
    ]);
```

Comment: Yes i have 2dsphere index in the model file: 
locationSchema.index({coords: '2dsphere'});

Also i have the near field name in the await section of the controller. I'm just following the async method described in their book

Comment: Try replacing the aggregate with a simple `Loc.find()`, just to make sure everything else is working right.

Comment: The problem fixed itself. Im not sure how